# How to restrict outgoing network access from EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am contracting out some ML tasks. I want all of the work the contractor does to be on a machine 'owned' by me without me buying them a physical machine, so I believe I want to spawn an EC2 instance (probably a preloaded DL machine). I plan to mount the data I want them to use for training (stored in an EBS volume) to this instance.

**I want** the contractor to be able to build/train models on this instance with data from the EBS and save code/model files to the EBS so that I can locally download the files and run models on my machine.

**I don't want** the contractor to be able to download the data or any model files onto their local machines.

These [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/security-iam.html) are helpful in describing different IAM access permissions, but I am really confused as to how to translate my specific needs into their language. I think they need read and write access to EC2 and EBS, but how can I be sure that **I have** the ability to locally download from the EBS **but they don't**?

Am I on the right track, or is there a different approach that is more efficient? I am very new to the AWS ecosystem. Thank you.

Comment: If they have access to login to the EC2 instance, then there is no way of preventing them from downloading things off the EC2 instance.

Comment: @MarkB I'm not sure why you say this. If outbound traffic is disallowed then how would they transfer the files anywhere?

Comment: @KeyanP You can't disallow outbound traffic on the port needed to allow login to the system. So they could always transfer data off the server on that port. For example if they are logging in via SSH, then they could transfer files off the system via SSH. If they are logging in via RDP, then they could transfer files off the system via RDP. If you tried to block the outbound network traffic, then you would break the ability to login to the system.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean, I am convinced! Thanks for elaborating Mark.

Comment: This might be suitable: [Nitro Enclaves](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/nitro/nitro-enclaves/)

Comment: That feature is unreleased, but looks relevant. I think even something like that would not make this task possible. Any user with read access could always `cat` the sensitive file and copy/paste to extract the content.